# "bus error" with a (very) simple opencv program (with Mac Os X)

Tags: c, macos, gcc, opencv

I know that "bus error" is often due to a programming errosr. But I really can not see such error in a three lines program :

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  IplImage *src = cvLoadImage("/tmp/Name.tiff", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
  IplImage* res = cvCreateImage( cvSize( 2, 2), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3 );
  cvSaveImage("/tmp/image.tiff", src);
  return 0;
}
```

I compile with the following:

```
gcc -I/Library/Frameworks/OpenCV.framework/Versions/A/Headers /usr/local/lib/libopencv_* test.c
```

Execution gives **bus error**.

Very important: if I remove the second line (the call to `cvCreateImage`), it works with no problems.

I'm using `opencv 2.3 and MacOs 10.8.5, gcc (i686-apple-darwin9-gcc-4.2.1 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5566)`

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace?  Also you **aren't** using Mac OS 10.8.5, that's for sure.

Comment: Did you try with a saner build command line (like specifying the libraries you need with `-l`, after your source file? (And do the headers you have there match to libraries you specify?)

Comment: Your compiler call is strange. Why not calling gcc with the `-f`(ramework) option instead ? It's precisely made to deal with paths and libraries inside frameworks correctly

Comment: did the call to cvLoadImage succeed?

Comment: Thanks @Mat. I have installed opencv from both the sources and MacPorts. My command line uses the first for the header and the latter for the linker...

Comment: @trojanfoe right it is 10.5.8

Comment: @user1379617: that's not what I asked. Are the headers you point to what you installed yourself? (Looks strange to have the headers in an "official" dir and the libraries in something custom) And your "linker" part is, sorry, bonkers. You're not supposed to do that at all.

Comment: you might want to release `res` once your done: `cvReleaseImage(&res);`

Comment: @Mat yes my gcc command is weird but it is the only one that worked for me... The issue was that the headers and the libs are not from the same opencv version. I uninstalled the packaged version and now with only the macport version, it works.

Answer (score 1):

You do not verify if `IplImage *src = cvLoadImage("/tmp/Name.tiff", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);` succeeded. I assume it fails to find file or decode it or whatever else. Everything rest is just consequence of bad engineering practice.

```
$ cat src/bus.cpp 
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  IplImage *src = cvLoadImage("/tmp/Name.tiff", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
  if(src==NULL) {
    printf("There is no /tmp/Name.tiff\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  IplImage* res = cvCreateImage( cvSize( 2, 2), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3 );
  cvZero(res);
  cvSaveImage("/tmp/Name.tiff", src);
  return 0;
} 
$ 
$ convert ~/ScanImage001.png /tmp/Name.tiff
$ ./bus 
$
```

works for me on Mac.